# What's the meaning of "knocking in my knees" in this sentence? and one more

Tags: meaning, differences

1. "I tug on my skirt, willing it to be longer, wanting it to cover the **knocking in my knees**."  -from the Hunger Games

What is the difference between "to cover my knees" and the sentence above?

All I know about "knocking" is a kind of "knocking the door" or "hit sth".

2. "My whole body's shaking. Hopefully, **it will be put down to excitement**." -from the Hunger Games

Does it mean 'I wish everybody would think the excitement cause shaking of my body'?

Thank you.

Comment: Shaking is a sign of fear: teeth chattering, knees knocking are ways to make the shaking more precise.  She wants to hide her fear not just her knees.

Comment: Aha!! you mean "knocking" is a kind of shaking from the fear. I see. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Just to clarify- her knees are shaking so badly that they are knocking together.

Comment: Yes "Hopefully it will be put down to..."  does mean "I wish everybody would think..." as you say.

Comment: Thank you, Jim and Hugh. Now I can understand the meaning of knocking..it must be the knocking "sound" of both knees because of fear.

Comment: @9ex9 - No, it's not the sound. It is the fact that the shaking knees are hitting each other, and this does not generally produce a sound.

Comment: Thanks, WhatRoughBeast. I thought it is a kind of sound because of the expression "knocking on the door...knock, knock". Then it might be just the description of shaking movement of joints. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

"Cover" in this context means "conceal".  "Knocking in my knees" is just an illiterate trying to say "knocking *of* my knees".

One's knees knocking (that is, shaking severely enough they are actually banging together) is a sign of stress, typically either anticipation or fear.

It is a weak metaphor because a skirt can literally cover the knees themselves, without necessarily concealing the fact that they are shaking.